# R Shiny create input using renderUI and function results

Tags: r, dynamic, input, shiny

I am new to R Shiny and I am trying to create an app which I need it to be as interactive as possible. One problem that I am dealing with is this. In the ui.R I have the following:

```
helpText("Select a feature"),
uiOutput("sliders")
```

And in the server.R:

```
output$sliders <- renderUI({
    selectInput('feature_name', 
                'Feature name', #Description  
                choice = c("F1"='1', "F2"='2'))
  })
```

My question is that is it possible to change something in renderUI so that instead of setting c("F1"='1', "F2"='2')) statically I can pass the results of a function to it so it can be more dynamic (a function which generates a feature list based on something that user does and passes the list to renderUI to create the selectInput). Something like following:

```
output$sliders <- renderUI({
    selectInput('feature_name', 
                'Feature name', #Description  
                choice = c(feature_creator(method)))
  })
```

Where "feature_creator" is a function and it returns: "F1"='1', "F2"='2' based on the method selected by user (variable "method" is defined and I have the value). My question to be more specific is what should "feature_creator" return as output?

Hope my question is clear enough. Let me know if I should add anything to the problem description.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Short answer - yes you can do that, but without a more specific question it is hard to give a real answer.

Comment: @JohnPaul just edited the question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all you really need is the `method` argument, this is not hard.

1) Make a `radioButtons()` input in your `ui` that will let the user select a method, lets give it `inputId="MethodChoice"`.

2) In your `choice` argument in the `selectInput` you should use `choice=c(feature_creator(input$MethodChoice))`

Then `feature_creator` will get a text value based on the method the user chooses.

In order to work in `choice`, `feature_creator` should return a named list, similar in format to what you hard-coded.

Comment: John I edited my question again. The method is defined and the thing that I  can not figure out is: what should feature_creator return so it looks like : "F1"='1', "F2"='2'. I have already tried returning it as a string which I am sure is incorrect and it is not  working.

Comment: Awesome. Named list, thats what I have been looking for all day. Thanks John